# PHPMailer sends email to different address and different body at the click of submit button

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
  $autoemail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

  $autoemail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP

  $autoemail->CharSet="utf-8";

  $autoemail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap

  $autoemail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

  $autoemail->AddAddress("example@gmail.com"); 
  $autoemail->AddReplyTo("example@gmail","EXAMPLE"); 

  $autoemail->WordWrap = 50; 

$autoemail->Subject="Hello";    
$autoemail->Body="Testing only";

if(!$autoemail->Send())
    {
        echo "Message was not sent";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $autoemail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }

$autoemail->ClearAllRecipients();

$autoemail->AddAddress("pleasehelp@gmail.com", "EXAMPLE"); 

$autoemail->Body="Testing Only";

if(!$autoemail->Send())
    {
        echo "Message was not sent";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $autoemail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
```

I want to send email to two different email addresses, but this coding gives me error that it sends the email twice to both addresses and after sending the email, my web page turns to white page saying it has error ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. Please help me on this! Thank you!

Comment: $autoemail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); ?

Comment: @Bernhard, there's nothing wrong with that - it's the correct FQCN.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, but you probably have a browser plugin or something causing multiple submissions. If you stick a random number on the end of your subject line, I expect you will find they will be different for each set of messages, indicating the script is running more than once, like this:

```
$autoemail->Subject="Hello".rand();
```

Looking at your access log may also reveal multiple requests.

The chunked encoding error doesn't appear to be anything to do with this script.

Comment: I found out that if I add json_ok() at the end of my code, it will send the email once to the first address but will not send anything to the second address. If I don't add it, emails will be sent to both addresses, but twice. Any idea why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: It's okay, I have found the issue. It's because I called the same function twice, therefore it submits the form twice then send the emails twice too. But thanks to those who responded they gave me the idea!!